# Is it true that there's an eraser for the Death Note that can bring people back to life?

Tags: death-note

While it was only mentioned one time in the pilot of the manga, one interesting detail about Death Note is that there was originally a way for the user of the note to reverse any of the deaths they carried out. Just as writing a name in the Death Note notebook would eventually kill a person, a special eraser existed that could not only physically get rid of the name written in the book, but even restore the life that was taken as well.

Comment: Yeah no, once a name is in the Note correctly that person is going to die, unless the Netflix movie writers are being silly.

Comment: @IG_42 I think in the Netflix movie there's an option to burn the page the name was written on to prevent the death.

Answer (score 10):

The Death Eraser appeared exclusively in the Death Note Pilot chapter, which isn't canon.

If the pilot chapter was considered canon several things would contradict themselves, like how the [Rules of the Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note) contain that there are infinite number of pages in the Death Note, while in the pilot version it is stated that it has 60 pages with 38 lines per page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that there is a Deathnote Eraser.

This occurrence can be found in a Short story in **'Death Note 13: How to Read Death Note'** book where Ryuk hands over an eraser to a new owner of the book, who happens to be a kid.

*Whereas in the actual Deathnote plot the Eraser isn't mentioned.*

Comment: The short story included in [b]How to read[b] is actually the [b]Death Note pilot[b].

Answer (score 0):

In the Netflix movie the rule is that you are aloud to burn one page and only one page and when you do it before that person dies then they will not die but Ryuk said you are not aloud to burn more then one page. which he could be lying and doesn't want you to back out of all the people you want to kill, but i fill like he isn't.

Answer (score -3):

Based on the netflix version, where one of the rules states that the death must be possible, ie no shark coming out of a toilet to bite the person, bringing back to life is not allowed.  So, if it can't happen under normal circumstances, it can't happen via Death Note.  It seems then that Death Note drives probability but it can't reach infinite improbability.

Edit addition:
Thus eraser is not possible as there is no probabilistic way to bring someone back from the dead.  Once someone is dead, they stay dead.  Also Gorzius agrees that it is the same in the manga/comic.

Comment: Yepp, this is also true in the manga/anime.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: I am negating eraser based on the fact that bringing someone back from the dead does not occur in normal/regular life.  I will add something about the eraser to make the link explicitly clear.